# Selecting specific pixel colour from layer

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am trying to write a photoshop script and there is certain behaviour i am not sure i can achieve.

One of my layers is called 'inks'. Its an empty layer that contains a drawing made from black and colour aliased pen.

I want to highlight the black pixels, copy them onto a new layer, and then delete them from the original inks layer.

is this possible.

i am new to scripting and i have my code to select my inks layer only:

```
#target photoshop

//Select inks layer
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.activeLayer = doc.artLayers.getByName("inks");
```

Any help on this problem would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Is the layer fully or partially transparent?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say empty layer. All that it contains is the aliased inks.

Comment: What do you mean, "empty layer"? It's got a transparent background?

Comment: Sorry, this is all new to me. Its just a layer with no background. All the layer contains is the aliased drawing. No white background,. You can see the checkered background if there is no other filled layer underneath the 'inks' layer.

Comment: Okay, so you're working with a layer that has a transparent background. I'm at work at the moment, but when I get off for the day (in about 2.5 hours) I can try to mess around in PS some and see what I can figure out. Quick question: I assume you're currently trying to separate black pixels from pixels with other colors?

Comment: Thankyou very much! Yes, that is correct. I want to separate the black pixels only from the layer.

Comment: Based on my experimentation, it's not feasible to select a single color from one layer without knowing the prior position of the color in said layer using scripts.

Comment: Thankyou for your help and consideration. If its not possible by script, i think i will separate them manually, calling one 'inks' and the other 'colour lines', or something similar. that way my script will be able to find them. Thanks again! :)

Comment: One more question if i may/ Its is probably a very simple one. How do i select layers using their position instead of their name? So, for example, how would i select the top most layer without actually knowing its name? :)

Comment: The topmost layer is always layer 0, so you can select it via `app.activeDocument.layers[0]`